# How to do C++ parameter array pointer arithmetic in Delphi

Tags: c++, arrays, delphi, pointers, delphi-7

In C++ you can send parameters that allow pointer arithmetic on arrays.  I need to be able to do that in a Delphi 7 project.  I tried doing it this way, but the receiving procedure is coughing. If an array pointer is incremented shouldn't c^[0] be at the new increment location?

The first procedure calls makect() but first moves the pointer to a memory location higher in the array by incrementing it. However the second procedure, when set to the array pointer position 0, does not like it. (of course there could be something else wrong, but I want to know if I am doing this correctly).

types listed here for clarity

```
type
  Pflt = ^flt;
  flt = double;

  Pflt_arr = ^flt_arr;
  flt_arr = array of flt;

  Pint_arr = ^int_arr;
  int_arr = array of integer;
```

constructor

```
constructor TRefT.Create(const length:integer);
begin
  len := length;
  SetLength(_ip, 2 + (1 shl trunc(ln(length / 4.0) / ln(2.0) + 0.5) shr 1) );
  _ip[0] := 0;
  SetLength(_w, length shr 1);
end;


procedure TRefT.CF(buff: pflt_arr);
begin
  rdft(len, 1, buff, @_ip, @_w);
end;
```

calling procedure

```
procedure TRefT.rdft(n:integer; isgn:integer; a:Pflt_arr; ip:Pint_arr; w:Pflt_arr);
var nw, nc: integer;
xi: flt;
begin
 nw := ip^[0];
 nc := ip^[1];
 if n > (nc shl 2) then
 begin
  nc := n shr 2;
  inc(w, nw);       <--attempt at pointer arithmetic
  makect(nc, ip, w); <-- C++ version is makect(nc, ip, w + nw);
 end;
end;
```

receiving procedure (with incremented array);

```
procedure TRefT.makect(nc:integer; ip:Pint_arr; c:Pflt_arr);
var j, nch: integer;
  delta: flt;
begin
ip^[1] := nc;
if nc > 1 then
 begin
    nch := nc shr 1;
    delta := arctan(1.0) / nch;
    c^[0] := cos(delta * nch);  <-- coughs here!
    c^[nch] := 0.5 * c^[0];
    for j := 1 to nch do
     begin
        c^[j] := 0.5 * cos(delta * j);
        c^[nc - j] := 0.5 * sin(delta * j);
     end;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: I've deleted my previous answer as it's no longer relevant. However, you'll need to show more code. I.e. How the array `w` is created before it's passed into `rdft`.

Comment: PS: Do you want multiple `flt_arr` arrays, or only a single `flt_arr` passed into `rdft`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. You've got an extra, erroneous, level of indirection. What you need here is pointers to static array of `Double` rather than pointers to dynamic array of `Double`.

Remember that a dynamic array is implemented as a pointer to the first element of the array. So your types are, in terms of indirection, equivalent to pointer to pointer to scalar.

One way to proceed is to declare types like this

```
type
  Pflt_arr = ^Tflt_arr;
  Tflt_arr = array [0..0] of flt;

  Pint_arr = ^Tint_arr;
  Tint_arr = array [0..0] of Integer;
```

and make sure change checking is disabled for this code.

This will allow you to write:

```
a^[i]
```

when `a` is of type `Pflt_array`.

What's more if you write:

```
inc(a, n);
```

then it will increment the address `a` by `n*sizeof(a^)` which is `n*sizeof(Tflt_array)` which is `n*sizeof(flt)*Length(a^))` which is `n*sizeof(flt)` which is exactly as you want.

This breaks down when you supply a constant expression as an index. As per this line:

```
nc := ip^[1];
```

Here the compiler will object that `1` is not in the range `0..0`. So you cannot have it both ways.

In this case you appear to need to crack the first two elements of `ip`. Which you can do like this:

```
type
  Phuge_int_arr = ^Thuge_int_arr; 
  Thuge_int_arr = array [0..(MaxInt div sizeof(Integer))-1] of Integer;
```

and then writing:

```
nc := Phuge_int_arr(ip)^[1];
```

That feels a little messy.

---

The alternative is to write the types like this:

```
type
  Pflt_arr = ^Tflt_arr;
  Tflt_arr = array [0..(MaxInt div sizeof(flt))-1] of flt;
```

That works fine for all indexing scenarios, and allows you to leave range checking enabled. But it makes pointer incrementing more difficult. Now you have to write:

```
inc(Pflt(a), n);
```

On balance, this latter approach is probably the lesser of the two evils.

---

The code that declares the actual storage still should use dynamic arrays, `SetLength` etc. When you need a `Pflt_array`, or a `Pint_array` cast the dynamic array:

```
Pflt_array(dyn_array)
```

This works because dynamic arrays are implemented as pointers to the first element of the array.

---

With the `0..0` variant, your code looks like this:

```
type
  Pflt = ^flt;
  flt = Double;

  Pflt_arr = ^Tflt_arr;
  Tflt_arr = array [0..0] of flt;

  Pint_arr = ^Tint_arr;
  Tint_arr = array [0..0] of Integer;

  Phuge_int_arr = ^Thuge_int_arr; 
  Thuge_int_arr = array [0..(MaxInt div sizeof(Integer))-1] of Integer;

....

constructor TRefT.Create(const length:integer);
begin
  len := length;
  SetLength(_ip, 2 + (1 shl trunc(ln(length / 4.0) / ln(2.0) + 0.5) shr 1) );
  SetLength(_w, length shr 1);
end;

procedure TRefT.CF(buff: pflt_arr);
begin
  rdft(len, 1, buff, Pint_arr(_ip), Pflt_arr(_w));
end;

procedure TRefT.rdft(n:integer; isgn:integer; a:Pflt_arr; ip:Pint_arr; w:Pflt_arr);
var nw, nc: integer;
    xi: flt;
begin
  nw := Phuge_int_arr(ip)^[0];
  nc := Phuge_int_arr(ip)^[1];
  if n > (nc shl 2) then
  begin
    nc := n shr 2;
    inc(w, nw);
    makect(nc, ip, w);
  end;
end;

procedure TRefT.makect(nc:integer; ip:Pint_arr; c:Pflt_arr);
var j, nch: integer;
    delta: flt;
begin
  Phuge_int_arr(ip)^[1] := nc;
  if nc > 1 then
  begin
    nch := nc shr 1;
    delta := arctan(1.0) / nch;
    c^[0] := cos(delta * nch);
    c^[nch] := 0.5 * c^[0];
    for j := 1 to nch do
    begin
      c^[j] := 0.5 * cos(delta * j);
      c^[nc - j] := 0.5 * sin(delta * j);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

Or the alternative using `0..(MaxInt div sizeof(scalar))-1` looks like this:

```
type
  Pflt = ^flt;
  flt = Double;

  Pflt_arr = ^Tflt_arr;
  Tflt_arr = array [0..(MaxInt div sizeof(flt))-1] of flt;

  Pint_arr = ^Tint_arr;
  Tint_arr = array [0..(MaxInt div sizeof(Integer))-1] of Integer;

....

constructor TRefT.Create(const length:integer);
begin
  len := length;
  SetLength(_ip, 2 + (1 shl trunc(ln(length / 4.0) / ln(2.0) + 0.5) shr 1) );
  SetLength(_w, length shr 1);
end;

procedure TRefT.CF(buff: pflt_arr);
begin
  rdft(len, 1, buff, Pint_arr(_ip), Pflt_arr(_w));
end;

procedure TRefT.rdft(n:integer; isgn:integer; a:Pflt_arr; ip:Pint_arr; w:Pflt_arr);
var nw, nc: integer;
    xi: flt;
begin
  nw := ip^[0];
  nc := ip^[1];
  if n > (nc shl 2) then
  begin
    nc := n shr 2;
    inc(Pflt(w), nw);
    makect(nc, ip, w);
  end;
end;

procedure TRefT.makect(nc:integer; ip:Pint_arr; c:Pflt_arr);
var j, nch: integer;
    delta: flt;
begin
  ip^[1] := nc;
  if nc > 1 then
  begin
    nch := nc shr 1;
    delta := arctan(1.0) / nch;
    c^[0] := cos(delta * nch);
    c^[nch] := 0.5 * c^[0];
    for j := 1 to nch do
    begin
      c^[j] := 0.5 * cos(delta * j);
      c^[nc - j] := 0.5 * sin(delta * j);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Take your pick!

---

FWIW you might take the opportunity whilst porting this code to change the `shl 2` and `shr 2` operations into arithmetic operations for the sake of clarity.

An option that you may not be aware of is not translating at all. Compile the original .c files into objects and link them statically using `$LINK`.

One final comment is that it is a shame you are stuck with such an old version of Delphi. Modern versions have the `$POINTERMATH` compiler option. This allows C style pointer arithmetic and indexing on plain pointer to scalar variables. A huge boon for such porting tasks.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying here. I changed my types (and constructor). Range checking is off by default, yet I am getting subrange bounds errors at compile. Adding {$R-} does not seem to make a difference. Is there something specific I should be doing to turn it off?

Comment: @Michelle Gah, sub-range bounds. That's when you have a constant expression like this: `nc := ip^[1]` and the compiler says no because it knows that `1` is out of bounds. Give me a minute to update again.

Comment: Instead of disabling range checking for one piece of code, I rather use `[0..SomethingSuitablyBig]` as array bounds. What `SomethingSuitablyBig` is depends on the situation, and can go up to `MaxInt div SizeOf(element) - 1`, but usually something like `65535` will do for most purposes.

Comment: @Rudy It depends. If you want to use `inc` on the pointer, `0..0` makes it simpler. `0..65535` is kind of useless if you leave range checking on for obvious reasons.

Comment: If this question is just about how to fix array pointer arithmetic, why not just do `makect(nc, ip, @w^[nw]);` and skip pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @LURD You can do that, but you do need to get the types defined correctly all the same

Comment: Yes indeed. I guess an implementation without pointers would look nicer from a pascal point of view.

Comment: @LURD It would. It's the getting there that is tricky. If you are porting from existing code that is known good, then keeping the translation as pure as possible makes it easier to be sure that you are correct. This weekend I translated 1300 lines of dense C code to perform sparse direct LU. I absolutely used `$POINTERMATH ON` and translated `double*` to `PDouble`. This is categorically the best way to go for a library of any size.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I usually used a pointer to a fake array. That means you can use indexing instead of Inc and Dec. For Inc and Dec I would not declare an array at all, just use the bare pointer. Nowadays, I use real pointer arithmetic on the bare pointer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree about the most literal conversion/translation, although that is not the usual Borland style. Their guide for public conversions requires you to use var parameters and pointers to arrays, if that is possible. I personally prefer an almost literal `PDouble` over a fake `PDoubleArray` or their `var Double`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, `{$POINTERMATH ON}`, `double*` --> `PDouble` and it's all good. That's what I would have said if the question did not mandate D7.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree about sticking close to the C/C++ code. Given the size of this code, going the 'recommended' Borland/Embarcadero way introduced more trouble than it was worth. D7 is what I have now. But I also need to be careful not to use too many Delphi specific solutions because FreePascal is being mentioned around here too. I tried to set a global var to 1 to get around that nasty const compiler complaint, but I see that I have lots of direct array constants 1,...,15! located throughout.

Comment: @LuRD tried to cast your @w^[nw] as a pflt_arr, but it didn't work. If inc() works at all, I think w needs to have information about its type, and I think that gets lost?

Comment: I think that you should have all the info at your disposal now. You know the options that are available. I think if it were me I would choose the second of the options, much as I dislike those huge array types.

Comment: The problem with @LURD's suggestion is that it yields an expression of type `^Double` that you then need to cast to whatever the receiving parameter expects. It will work but there is simply no 100% clean solution without $POINTERMATH

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answer is not an attempt to answer the question at hand. David did that and presented ways to handle the pointer arithmetics.

I don't know how much code you have similar to what is presented here. Working with pointers can be cumbersome and sometimes leads to simple mistakes when typecasting.

A more straight Delphi solution would be to work with dynamic arrays, and declare methods with open arrays.

A solution with your example would look like this:

```
Type
 TRefT = class
 private
   len : Integer;
   _ip : array of integer;
   _w  : array of double;
 public
   Constructor Create(const length : integer);
   procedure CF(const buff : array of double);  // Or var
   procedure rdft(       n    : integer;
                         isgn : integer;
                   const a    : array of double;  // Or var
                     var ip   : array of integer;
                     var w    : array of double);
   procedure makect(     nc : integer;
                         nw : integer; // c array index offset
                     var ip : array of integer;
                     var c  : array of double);
 end;
```

---

```
constructor TRefT.Create(const length:integer);
begin
  len := length;
  SetLength(_ip, 2 + (1 shl trunc(ln(length / 4.0) / ln(2.0) + 0.5) shr 1) );
  SetLength(_w, length shr 1);
end;

procedure TRefT.CF(const buff: array of double);
begin
  rdft(len, 1, buff, _ip, _w);
end;

procedure TRefT.rdft(       n    : integer;
                            isgn : integer;
                      const a    : array of double;
                        var ip   : array of integer;
                        var w    : array of double);
var
  nw, nc: integer;
begin
  nw := ip[0];
  nc := ip[1];
  if n > (nc shl 2) then
  begin
    nc := n shr 2;
    makect(nc, nw, ip, w);
  end;
end;

procedure TRefT.makect(     nc : integer;
                            nw : integer;  // c array index offset
                        var ip : array of integer;
                        var c  : array of double);
var
  j, nch: integer;
  delta: double;
begin
  ip[1] := nc;
  if nc > 1 then
  begin
    nch := nc shr 1;
    delta := ArcTan(1.0) / nch;
    c[nw] := Cos(delta * nch);
    c[nch + nw] := 0.5 * c[nw];
    for j := 1 to nch do
    begin
      c[j + nw] := 0.5 * Cos(delta * j);
      c[nc - j + nw] := 0.5 * Sin(delta * j);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you have large c++ libraries to translate, I would suggest to follow David's recommendations, otherwise this more pascal/Delphi like way is easier to work with.

Comment: I generally agree, but look at all those additions that were needed! I am in discussions to see if this can't be done in a more recent version of Delphi, so that $POINTERMATH can be used. I' upping your answer though because your contributions have been very helpful.

Comment: @Michelle: Which solution you choose depends on whether you have control over the code or not, and if you must only interface with Delphi or with other languages too. Generally, the fake array method is the recommended one. But only if the `double *` really points to an array (or is nil). For Delphi and C++Builder only, the pure Delphi way shown above is much easier.